# What kind of chili turns brown and shrivels when ripening on the plant?

Tags: vegetables, identification, chili

I have a few of these chili plants growing and they produce a longish (approx 4", sometimes curled chili that turns brown and begins to shrivel (slightly) when it ripens. It does not transition to a different, more standard colour (red/orange) and I know that this is the right colour, because the seeds packet that I bought had a picture of a brownish chili that was shriveled on the outside.

However, I did not bother saving the packet and I do not recall what type of chili it was. I couldn't find new packets in the store to check either (perhaps I could just take a fruit in and they could identify, but that's what this site is for!). Does anyone know what type of chilli this might be?

If it helps, these chilies are by far the mildest I've ever seen. I can eat them straight off the plant raw/ripe without wincing and they don't burn the tongue one tiny bit.

[image]

Comment: Can't see anything in the sweet pepper section of Rosalind Creasy's "The Edible Pepper Garden". Is it possible that it is a hotter variety which has crossed with neighboring sweet peppers? Also it could be a dark brown variety of a pepper that is better known as red/green/etc.

Comment: About 10 of these and a lone [bell pepper plant](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/why-did-my-jalapenos-turn-black/1646#1646) are the only ones from the family I have at the moment. I remember that I bought it because I _thought_ it was hot. The chillies on nearly all the plants turn brown (and don't progress from there). Your last point could be true though.

Comment: my guess (& it really is a guess, using the information in your question) from an internet search: [Poblano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poblano) or [Guajillo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guajillo_chili).

Comment: also have you seen and/or tried, [Chile Varieties Database](http://www.g6csy.net/chile/database.html)?

Comment: @MikePerry Thank you very much. I wasn't aware of that link and I'll try my luck later in the day when I get some time. Also, re: your earlier comment, it does look _a lot_ like a miniature poblano. The wrinkles, curves & depressions are very typical poblano, although it never fattens up like poblanos do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out what variety these are! They're called Pasilla bajio, a variety of *Capsicum annum* and is a Mexican heirloom chile pepper plant. Here is what Mike Perry's handy [chile varieties database](http://www.g6csy.net/chile/database.html) link had to say:

> Pasilla means 'little raisin' in Spanish, referring to the wrinkled, deep brown dried pods and raisin-like aroma of this flavourful chile no good cook should be without. The elongated, cylindrical pods measure 6 to 8 inches long and an inch wide. Delicious either fresh or dried, at the immature stage the beautiful fruits are a remarkable, glossy, deep forest-green colour that matures to dark chocolate brown. The TMV resistant plants grow 2 to 3 feet tall, with branches beginning 5 to 6 inches from the low stem so pods don't touch the ground. The dried pods of this delicious pepper form the basis for the rich complex flavour of Mole sauces where no heat is required. Heat level is 0.5 (Capsicum annuum)

[This site](http://www.cherrygal.com/pepperspicypasillabajioheirloomseeds2010-p-12302.html) also confirms my "sweet pepper" experience.

> PASILLA ("Little Raisin") BAJIO PEPPER is the sweetest chile you will find - practically no serious heat (though depending on the weather it may surprise you - sustained hot weather turns the burner up on hot peppers), but a most intriguing and uniquely herbal/floral taste that will lend complexity to any dish!