# What is this discolouration of the skin of my pepper?

Tags: diagnosis, peppers, bell-peppers

One of my peppers is showing some strange discolouration of its skin. You cannot feel that it's there, so presumably this is underneath the outermost membrane of the fruit. As far as I can tell there is only one fruit effected so far.

Here are two images of the affected fruit from different angles, so you can see what I mean.

[image: cropped photo of effected pepper, showing discolouration of skin]
[image: cropped photo of effected pepper, showing discolouration of skin]

What's wrong with this fruit?
Do I need to "fix" it, and how can I?
Do I need to worry about the other fruit on this plant?
Will this be safe to eat or should I cut it off and dispose of it?

Comment: See the answer to [Why did my jalapeños turn black](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/why-did-my-jalapenos-turn-black/1646#1646). I believe the answer is the same and the exact same thing happened to my bell pepper before they turned into the shade in the picture in my answer there (see revision 2 pic for something closer to this). So let me know if it answered your question, and I'll close it as a duplicate.

Comment: I'll have to keep an eye on it and report back when there's a change.

Comment: Agree with yoda. Black is the transitional colour between green and red for most of my plants in the capsicum genus. If you want green peppers, pick now. If you want red ones then wait til they turn red.

Comment: @DMA57361: did it eventually turn red?

Comment: @bstpierre I... honestly can't remember. I'd completely forgotten I had a question open still. :/ We ended the season last year with some green and some red peppers, but I couldn't tell you which came from which plants (plus, they were eaten some time ago!) or if the fruit pictured was red or now.

Answer (score 3):

See the answer to [Why did my jalapeños turn black?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/Why/did/my/jalepeno/turn/bl/1646#1646) As stated above it is the same ripening discoloration in both cases. It is not a problem and will disappear as the plant ripens. It is more common on hot peppers than bell peppers, but occurs regularly on both.